# Problem adding a class to a select box parent via jQuery, as is it applies to all select box parents on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, this

I'm having a little trouble with jQuery, I wish to have 3 separate select boxes, and when a select box is chosen the parent div then gets given that selected Option text as a class. I am having issues however as it instead displays all of the values on the page instead of the individual one.

I have tried using (this) but I had no luck with it unfortunately.

**My aim** is to click the middle box for example and change the option to 'Blue', so then it's parent div is

`<div class="tableoptioncontainer  Blue "</div>`

but instead **the problem** is this

`<div class="tableoptioncontainer  ColourBlueColour"</div>`

https://jsfiddle.net/jack319082/psLtarno/6/

HTML:

```
<div class="row-container">

  <div class="tableoptioncontainer">
    <select id="selectbox">
      <option>Colour</option>
      <option>Red</option>
      <option>Orange</option>
      <option>Light Orange</option>
      <option>Yellow</option>
   </select>
  </div>


  <div class="tableoptioncontainer">
   <select id="selectbox">
     <option>Colour</option>
     <option>Light Blue</option>
     <option>Blue</option>
     <option>Dark Blue</option>
      <option>Violet</option>
   </select>
  </div>

  <div class="tableoptioncontainer">
    <select id="selectbox">
      <option>Colour</option>
      <option>Dark Green</option>
     <option>Moss</option>
      <option>Green</option>
      <option>Aqua</option>
   </select>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row-container {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tableoptioncontainer {
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 8px 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


/* Background Colours for when it works */
.Red {background-color: #ff0000}
.Orange {background-color: #ff9000}
.Light-Orange {background-color: #ffc272}
.Yellow {background-color: #fff225}
.Light-Blue {background-color: #8bc2ff}
.Blue {background-color: #0078ff}
.Dark-Blue {background-color: #0030ba}
.Violet {background-color: #4603dd}
.Dark-Green {background-color: #00390f}
.Moss {background-color: #009126}
.Green {background-color: #00f13e}
.Aqua {background-color: #00f1d2}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

      jQuery("select").change(function(){
          var colourName = jQuery('select#selectbox :selected').text();
          colourName = colourName.replace(/ /g, '-');
     jQuery(this).parent().attr('class','tableoptioncontainer');
          jQuery(this).parent().addClass(colourName);
       });

});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question appears formatted correctly. Enjoy your stay!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your script like this

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("select").change(function(){
      var colourName = jQuery(this).find('option:selected').text();
      colourName = colourName.replace(/ /g, '-');
      jQuery(this).parent().attr('class','tableoptioncontainer');
      jQuery(this).parent().addClass(colourName);
   });
 });
```

Your declaration `var colourName = jQuery('select#selectbox :selected').text();` selects the text of the selected options from all 3 selectboxes.
And note that ids have to be unique, you have the same `id="selectbox"` for all selects.

Comment: Great stuff mate it worked thankyou! I know about the id's, its not like that on the main site but just rushed the example, still sholuldn't be putting them though. Cheers!

Comment: @jack2505 Glad that I was able to help you :) If this answered your question, please check the checkmark next to the answer to resolve your question as answered.